# C++ set search for pair element?

Tags: c++, search, stl, std-pair, stdset

So I have a set of `pairs<string ,string>`

And I want to use `find()` to search for a single string which would be in the "first" of the pair, then if I find that string in first I want to return second from that function.

My current attempt is..

```
myList::iterator i;

i = theList.find(make_pair(realName, "*"));

return i->second;
```

Comment: Why are you not using a `map`? Other notes: if it is a `std::set`, why is it called `myList`? Have you created a comparison function for `std::pair`s? How does it look like?

Answer (score 6):

Is C++11 acceptable?

```
auto it = find_if(theList.begin(), theList.end(),
    [&](const pair<string, string>& val) -> bool {
        return val.first == realName;
    });

return it->second;
```

Or in C++03, first define a functor:

```
struct MatchFirst
{
        MatchFirst(const string& realName) : realName(realName) {}

        bool operator()(const pair<string, string>& val) {
                return val.first == realName;
        }

        const string& realName;
};
```

then call it like so:

```
myList::iterator it = find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), MatchFirst(realName));
return it->second;
```

This will only return the first match, but from your question, it looks like that's all you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::set<std::pair<std::string, std::string> >` for this but you will need a custom
comparison object for this because the pair's relational operator takes both elements for this. That said, it seems as if you actually should use a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` instead.

Comment: I disagree, the semantics would be quite different, notably the inability to store several items with the same "key". A `multimap` could be closer in terms of semantics, but then would not guarantee the uniqueness of the pair which might also be desirable. Without knowing the requirement, your answer really is a shot in the dark...

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `<` for `std::pair` implements a lexicographical order and `""` is the minimum element for strings. Combining this we get:

```
 typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> StringPair;
 typedef std::set<StringPair> Set;

 std::string const* find_first(Set const& s, std::string const& key) {
   Set::const_iterator const it = s.lower_bound(std::make_pair(key, ""));

   // Check that it actually points to a valid element whose key is of interest.
   if (it == s.end() or it->first != key) { return 0; }

   // Yata!
   return &it->second;
 }
```

The trick is using `lower_bound` appropriately.

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element which does not compare less than `value`.

- If it returns `end()`, then it did not find anything interesting.
- Otherwise, `it->first >= key` so we get rid of the `>` case (of no interest to us)

I would point out though that this only returns the first element of the range. If you are interested in all elements, try:

```
typedef std::pair<Set::const_iterator, Set::const_iterator> SetItPair;

SetItPair equal_range_first(Set const& s, std::string const& key) {
  StringPair const p = std::make_pair(key, "");
  return std::make_pair(s.lower_bound(p), s.upper_bound(p));
}
```

This will return the full range of nodes in `s` whose first element is equal to `key`. You then just have to iterate over this range:

```
for (Set::const_iterator it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it) {
  // do something
}
```

And you don't even have to worry whether the return of `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` was end or not.

- if `lower_bound` returns `end()`, then so does `upper_bound`, and the loop is skipped
- if `lower_bound` points to a node for which `it->first > key`, then `upper_bound` will point to that same node, and the loop is skipped

That is the power of ranges: no need to make special checks, the ranges just end up empty when there is no match, and so the loop over them... is skipped in a single check.

Comment: what if the second element is an int?